# (How) Is it possible to set nodes' "args" attribute from a parameter?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In launch files nodes have an "args" attribute that are used to pass command line arguments to a node. It is sometimes important to get those arguments from another place; from a parameter, for example.

Is there a way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11502/(how)-is-it-possible-to-set-nodes%27-%22args%22-attribute-from-a-parameter?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you cannot get that value from a parameter unless your code explicitly looks for a parameter.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-10-12**:
Actually the other way around would be simpler: Always read from a parameter and pass _myparam:=value as a cmd line parameter.